# Haskell: [IO ()] to IO ()

Tags: haskell, io-monad

Haskell wiki has the following question:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Higher-order_functions

`for :: a -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> (a -> IO ()) -> IO ()
for i p f job = -- ???`

I was able to come up with the following implementation:

```
generate :: a -> (a->Bool) -> (a->a) -> [a]
generate s cnd incr = if (cnd s) then [] else [s] ++ generate (incr s) cnd incr

-- collapse :: [IO ()] -> IO ()
-- collapse (x:xs) = x ++ collapse xs
-- does not work ^^^^^^


for::a->(a->Bool)->(a->a)->(a->IO())->IO()
for s cnd incr ioFn = map (ioFn) (generate s cnd incr)
```

Ofcourse `map (ioFn) (generate s cnd incr)` results in `[IO ()]`. I am not sure how this can be transformed to `IO ()`
I need something like `foldl` but the one that works with `[IO ()]` instead of `[a]`.

Comment: You canuse [**sequence_**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence-95-)

Comment: `generate s cnd incr = takeWhile cnd (iterate incr s)`

Comment: `[IO ()]` is a more specific instance of `[a]` (in which `a` is `IO ()`) so you can pass it to `foldl`. Also you can ask hoogle this kind of question: https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%5BIO%20()%5D%20-%3E%20IO%20()&scope=set%3Ahaskell-platform

Comment: Apart from `sequence_`, you could write this as a fold directly using e.g. `foldr (*>) (pure ())` (or `foldr (>>) (return ())`). This is more or less what `sequence`/`sequence_`/`sequenceA` do: join up the actions using applicative/monadic sequencing (`*>`/`>>`) with the “base case” being an action that does nothing (`pure ()`/`return ()`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function you are looking for is:

```
sequence_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m ()
```

But we can actually just replace `map`, such that we do not need an extra function. You can use [**`mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM) here instead of `map`, so:

```
for :: a -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> (a -> IO ()) -> IO()
for s cnd incr ioFn = mapM_ ioFn (generate s cnd incr)
```

This thus will apply the function `ioFun` on all elements of `generate s cnd incr`, and eventually return the unit `()`.